# Electrical Circuit with Fourier Transform

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm working in my Electrical Circuits homeworks. One of the exercises says: "Use the Fourier Transform method to calculate \$v_0(t)\$"
The circuit is this:

[image: Circuit]

where \$v_g=36sgn(t)\$, and \$sgn(t)\$ is the sign of \$t\$ (it returns 1, -1 or 0). Well, my problem is the following. I consulted my table of Fourier Transforms and I found that $$V_g(\omega)=36\cdot \dfrac{2}{j\omega}$$
However, I don't know how to calculate \$\omega\$. I need it in order to calculate the \$V_g\$ and also \$Z_C\$. I know that, if, for example \$v_g(t)=A\sin(kt)\$ then \$k=\omega\$. But in this case I'm completely lost.

How can I do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I don't know how to calculate ω

There's no reason to calculate \$\omega\$.  Your approach should be to find the frequency domain representation of the output voltage, \$V_o(j \omega)\$, and transform *that* back to the time domain.

In the frequency domain and by voltage division

$$V_o(j\omega) = V_g(j\omega)\dfrac{60k\Omega||\frac{1}{j\omega 2\mu F}}{12k\Omega + 60k\Omega||\frac{1}{j\omega 2\mu F}} $$

Comment: What do the || mean? Is that the notation for angle?

Comment: The || means "in parallel with", so you need to calculate the equivalent impedance of two impedances in parallel.

Comment: That's true, I realized yesterday. Thank for your answer! :D I think I'll have no problems doing the inverse transform.

Answer (score 1):

The voltages and currents in the circuit do not oscillate at a single frequency $\omega$. Your Fourier transform table is telling you that $v_g(t)$ in this case can be written as the superposition

$$ v_g(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty V_g(\omega) e^{j\omega t}\, d\omega = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{36\times 2}{j\omega} e^{j\omega t}\, d\omega.$$

Recalling that voltage obeys the superposition principle, do you see what to do from here?

*Expansion of the above:* Forget for the moment that you've been asked to compute the response to \$v_g(t)\$; instead, suppose that the driving voltage is \$\tilde{v}_g(t) = A_g e^{j\omega t}\$. This is what you mentioned in your original question, although here I've switched to using complex phasor notation. Keep in mind that \$A_g\$ may be complex: \$A_g = |A_g|e^{j\phi_g}\$.

Using the Kirchoff loop laws and what you know about the impedances of resistors and capacitors, you should be able to find the sinusoidal voltage across the 60 kΩ resistor:

$$\tilde{v}_0(t) = A_0 e^{-j\omega t},$$

where \$A_0\$ is another complex number. You'll find that

$$ A_0 = f(\omega) A_g $$

for some function \$f(\omega)\$ [hint: it will be a rational function of \$\omega\$].

What does this mean? Well, your Fourier table has told you that the driving voltage \$v_g(t) = 36\mathrm{sgn}(t)\$ has an oscillatory component \$A_g e^{j\omega t}\$ with \$A_g = V_g(\omega) = 36\times 2/j\omega\$. Therefore, the voltage \$v_0(t)\$ has an oscillatory component \$A_0 e^{j\omega t}\$ with \$A_0 = V_0(\omega) = f(\omega) V_g(\omega)\$. Therefore, \$v_0(t)\$ must be given by

$$ v_0(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty V_0(\omega) e^{j\omega t}\, d\omega = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(\omega) V_g(\omega) e^{j\omega t}\, d\omega.$$

Depending on your professor's/grader's expectations, you may be expected to find an analytic expression for this integral.

Comment: I understand that I have more than one $\omega$, but I don't see how to apply that that inverse Fourier t. Could you explain a bit more, please? n.n